# Basic algebra problem - two equations and two unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This should be dead simple but is still beyond my reach. According to wolfram alpha

$$1/4 x = x^2 + y^2$$

$$ -Y = x^2 + y^2$$

has two non zero solutions, x = 4/17 and Y = -1/17, but I cannot get it. Elimination only seems to reduce the problem to one equation with two unknowns and substitution gives me an endless mess. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Subtract one equation from the other and get $(1/4)x+y=0$.

Answer (score 2):

From both equations,

$-y = \frac 14 x$ ......(3)

Squaring both sides,

$y^2 = \frac 1{16} x^2$

Put value of $y^2$ and $y$ in equation (2),

$\frac 14 x = x^2 + \frac 1{16} x^2$

$4x = 17x^2$

$4 = 17x$

$x = \frac 4{17}$

Then find $y$ from equation (3).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$-y = \frac14x$$

$$y^2 =\frac1{16}x^2$$

Now you can substitute this into your first equation and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a linear algebra problem, because the equations are quadratic instead of linear. We have $$x/4=x^2+y^2=-y\Rightarrow x=-4y$$ plugging this into the second equation gives $-y=(-4y)^2+y^2=17y^2$ so $y=0$ or $y=-1/17$. Then we use $x=4y$ to find out that the two solutions are $(0,0)$ and $(4/16,-1/17)$

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. I changed the title and tag. Thanks.